# How to add a Cycles Modifier in Blender?

Tags: animation, blender, 3d-modelling

I am trying to add a Cycles modifier to a curve in Blender's NLA Editor.

I am doing this as I follow the following tutorial on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4TkA5P5Qes. At 12m05s into the video, he adds a Cycles modifier to make the animation loop infinitely.

However, when I try to add this, the modifier is greyed out.

[image]

At first I assumed the modifier would still work, but it does not. As you can see, the line does not continue infinitely. My animation stops at the last frame. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I have racked my brain over this for at least an hour.

Below is a picture of my whole blender layout incase just for more information. I am using Blender v2.78. If needed, my .blend file can be found at -
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Iu9rAwhmALWGNZbTJaQi1yX3c

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the graph editor we have several controls located with each channel as well as for all channels in a group.

The eye icon hides the curve.

The padlock icon locks the channel so that it cannot be edited.

The speaker icon mutes the channel so that it is not used during animation playback.

The spanner icon disables modifiers.

In your case you appear to have clicked the spanner for the bone so that all modifiers on all body bone channels have been disabled. Just click the spanner in the body group header to re-enabled them.